# Visual studio 2003 web projects

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2003

I have a requirement to work on a VS2003 web project.

I have VS2008,vs2010,vs2003 installed in my system

Other System details are
Windows Xp professional version 2 service pack 3. IIS 5.1

When i am trying to create a VS 2003 web project giving the localhost as path
i am getting the following  error.
`visual studio noted that specified web server is not running under asp .net 1.1 version.You will be unable to run asp .net web applications or services`

I have used aspnet_regiis commands as well as a tool(ASPNETVersionSwitcher.exe ) to swith versions and in IIS also default web site ASP.NET version chosen as ASP.NET 1.14322.

I am still getting the error.

same error I get ,if I point a virtual directory in the existing 1.1 .NET web application and trying to open it.

Please advise, I have to work on this project as soon as possible.

Comment: Is there some sort of conflict with the .NET framework versions? I've had this problem where .NET 2.0 and above conflict with .NET 1.1 and only programs targeting one or the other will work: you have to uninstall 1.1 or uninstall 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all IIS Applications are using the same version of the framework. It is possible to have both 1.x and 2. I typically, uninstall using `aspnet_regiis /ua` which uninstalls all ASP.NET versions, then use `aspnet_regiis` to install ASP.NET as needed.

Make sure the "Virutual Directory" ASP.NET properties are correct for the version of Visual Studio you are using. Obviously, you cannnot use VS2k3 to connect to a ASP.NET 2.0 Virtual Directory.

Following is a dump of my installed ASP.NET versions.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>aspnet_regiis -lv
1.1.4322.0      Valid (Root)    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\asp
net_isapi.dll
2.0.50727.0     Valid           C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\as
pnet_isapi.dll
4.0.30319.0     Valid           C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\as
pnet_isapi.dll
```

---

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>aspnet_regiis -lk
W3SVC/  1.1.4322.2443
W3SVC/1/ROOT/   2.0.50727.0
W3SVC/1/ROOT/Reports/   2.0.50727.0
W3SVC/1/ROOT/ReportServer/      2.0.50727.0
W3SVC/1/ROOT/ExceptionService/  2.0.50727.0
W3SVC/1/ROOT/verification/      2.0.50727.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen people create a virtual machine (pc) using Windows XP as the guest OS.  They would then install Visual Studio 2003 on the virtual machine and do their development there.

From what I gather those people ran into a similar issue like yours.

Another solution that I have heard was that Visual Studio 2003 needs to be installed **first**, before Visual Studio 2005, 2008, or 2010 are installed.  I've heard that works, but only from a clean OS install (you can't uninstall all the versions and start over.)